# ckeditor will not open code snippet correctly

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, code-snippets

I am using ckeditor 4.4 with the plugin code snippet. If I create a document with a rich code snippet and save everything works great. The source code for what is created is

```
<pre><code>&lt;p&gt;this is a paragraph&lt;/p&gt;</code></pre>
```

Which is how the plugin is supposed to work.

When I then edit this document, opening it back up in ckeditor like so

```
<textarea name = 'materials' class='ckeditor'><?php echo $lesson['materials'] ?></textarea>
```

The editor distorts the code snippet changing the source code to:

```
<pre>

&nbsp;</pre>

<p><code>this is a paragraph</code></p>
```

Am I opening the text with ckeditor incorrectly or is this a known problem that I have not been able to find a solution for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `htmlspecialchars` before printing out HTML in `<textarea>` otherwise your `&lt;p&gt;` is automatically decoded to `<p>`. This has been discussed many times on Stackoverflow and [CKEditor's forum](http://ckeditor.com/forums).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that needs it, the equivalent to `htmlspecialchars` in CFML is `HTMLEditFormat`.